# Collate field in package Description

Tags: r, package

I apologize as I know that this answer is likely in the manuals for writing an R package but in my reading and looking at other package's Collate fields I can't figure out 100% what this field is for.  In plain language (mine is English) what does the Collate field in the Description file of a package do?  What would one want to put there?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think it comes from a time and situation when the order in which the files in the `R/` directory were sourced (as opposed to the lexicographic default) still mattered.  A similar reason for why the `.onLoad()` function is often in a file named `zzz.R`.

For what it is worth, not one of my packages uses the "Collate:" field in DESCRIPTION.

*Edit:*  And as we're fond of empirical measures, here is a quick `grep` on a machine with all CRAN sources:

```
$ grep ^Collate */DESCRIPTION | wc -l
292
$ ls -1 */DESCRIPTION | wc -l
3779
```

So that is 7.7% of all packages.  I really would not worry about this unless you *really* must.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that's helpful.

Comment: About 30% of Bioconductor packages have a Collate field. Not sure that "from a time" leaves the correct impression, one still organizes code into files, and the order that files are collated matters. E.g., S4 methods need to be defined after generics, and classes should be defined before the methods that use them or classes that contain them. The perversity of lexicographic sort in non-C locales makes one wary of relying on an automatic collation order (maybe R collates files in a C locale? Too subtle for me).

Comment: Hah--I almost added that it may have something to do with S4 classes (which I generally still don't use all that much...)  But even then one can of course have classes, generics, methods in that order in the same file as we do in Rcpp. So Collate: remains a useful if rarely used option, and Tyler was not missing anything essential.

Comment: The devtools package (through roxygen2?) creates this from the @include directive. It allows one to avoid the use of kludges like zzz.R

Comment: Ah, if in doubt we can always blame Hadley :)  Also, most of the time you don't really need zzz.R any more, and R 2.15.1 will bring more changes on that front.